# Is ~楽しんでいただけましたら、幸いです past tense or not?

Tags: grammar, tense, keigo

I'm trying to say "I'm happy if you enjoyed..." or "I hope you enjoyed", but this is keigo, so I got a bit confused. If I were to say xxx 楽しんでいただけましたら、幸いです does that mean "I hope you enjoyed xxx" or is it not past tense, meaning "I hope you will enjoy xxx"?

Comment: I think this is more like "i hope you enjoyed yourself." It isn't future tense, so you say it after the fact.

Comment: ^ frei, we often say (XXを)楽しんで｛いただけましたら/いただけたら/いただければ/いただけると｝｛幸いです/嬉しいです｝、楽しんで｛くれたら/くれれば｝嬉しいです etc. to mean "I hope you'll enjoy XX."

Answer (score 2):

This is not past tense. The ～たら is one of the conditional forms, regardless if it's a keigo or not.
In this case, I wouldn't use this form because the condition is not necessary. Basically, it means you're happy if and only if they enjoyed.

I would say more something like 楽しんでいただいて良かったです。Literally "You enjoyed and I'm happy". This construction is very common.

Comment: But what if I don't know if they enjoyed it? Is it good then, too?

Comment: Yes, at this stage, knowing if they actually enjoyed or not is not the point. You should always express your best feelings, period. (Anyway, they'll never tell you if they actually enjoyed or not. It's not in they're habits). Just get used to it !

Comment: @user18408 In that case you could say ｛楽しんでいただけたのでしたら・楽しんでいただけたのなら・楽しんでいただけたのであれば｝｛幸いで‌​す・うれしいです・何よりです｝ etc.

Comment: LuTo - Even in English culture, it is pretty normal to understate the value of what you have given in one breath, even to turn businesslike in the next.   As in:
"We hope you have enjoyed the show,   
Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Heart's Club Band,   
We're sorry but it's time to go "

Answer (score 2):

One of the typical situation could be the following. (I'm not confident my English transration, but I hope you can understand the context and the nuance of "楽しんでいただけましたら幸い".)

> この大相撲夏場所のチケットを差し上げます。
>   Here is the ticket for Summer Grand Sumo Tournament. It's for you.
>
> ご興味{きょうみ}があるかどうか存{ぞん}じ上{あ}げませんが、楽しんでいただけましたら幸いです。
>   I don't know if you would be interested in it, but if I could have you enjoy it, I'll be happy.
>
> This sentence "楽しんでいただけましたら" can be used for the future occurrence and the past occurrence.
>   The above example shows the future occurrence.

If you'd like to make clear the tense, you can say the followings.

> future: "（もし）楽しんでいただけるのであれば幸いです"
>   past: "（もし）楽しんでいただけたのであれば幸いです"